# How to draw a line over a picturebox and display the distance in kilometers between two points depending on the scale factor in the map image?

Tags: c#, winforms

I just did PrtScrn and saved in paint the image of this part of map.
on the map the scale is 5km or 3km not sure what is the real one in the bottm right corner.

I added the image to pictureBox and depending on the scale on the map in the image I want to draw on the picturebox and display real world distance of the line in kilometers.

but the distance it's calculating and showing not even close to the real world.

This is what I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Map_Drawer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Point startPoint; // Store the starting point for drawing
        private Point endPoint; // Store the current endpoint for drawing
        private const double ScaleKilometers = 5.0; // The known scale in kilometers

        bool isDrawing;
        // our collection of strokes for drawing
        List<List<Point>> _strokes = new List<List<Point>>();
        // the current stroke being drawn
        List<Point> _currStroke;
        // our pen
        Pen _pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            startPoint = e.Location; // Set the starting point
            isDrawing = true;
            // mouse is down, starting new stroke
            _currStroke = new List<Point>();
            // add the initial point to the new stroke
            _currStroke.Add(e.Location);
            // add the new stroke collection to our strokes collection
            _strokes.Add(_currStroke);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDrawing)
            {
                // record stroke point if we're in drawing mode
                _currStroke.Add(e.Location);
                Refresh(); // refresh the drawing to see the latest section
            }

            if (startPoint != Point.Empty)
            {
                endPoint = e.Location;

                // Calculate and display the distance between the two points based on the scale
                double distance = CalculateDistance(startPoint, endPoint);
                labelDistance.Text = $"Distance: {distance:F2} units"; // Display the distance on a label
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            startPoint = Point.Empty;
            endPoint = Point.Empty;
            isDrawing = false;
        }

        private double CalculateDistance(Point startPoint, Point endPoint)
        {
            // Measure the distance between two points (startPoint and endPoint) based on the known 5km scale
            double imageWidth = pictureBox1.Width;
            double pixelDistance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(endPoint.X - startPoint.X, 2) + Math.Pow(endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y, 2));

            // Calculate the real-world distance based on the scale
            double realWorldDistance = (pixelDistance / imageWidth) * ScaleKilometers;

            return realWorldDistance;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // now handle and redraw our strokes on the paint event
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            foreach (List<Point> stroke in _strokes.Where(x => x.Count > 1))
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(_pen, stroke.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the picturebox with the image.

The form size and picturebox size are both is the same as the map image file size:  1263x817
the picturebox size mode is Normal.

[image: picturebox with the image map inside]

Comment: `double realWorldDistance = (imageWidth / pixelDistance) * ScaleKilometers;` -- Replace `Refresh()` (that's the whole Form) with `pictureBox1.Invalidate();`

Comment: The length of the right most blue line is what 5km is. Not 5km / image width. And afaik, giggle maps should have an api for distance measurement in a map.